# How to remove PWA service worker from domain

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, dns, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I was running an React PWA on my domain (example.com). Now I changed the DNS A record to an server running Wordpress. The problem is that old useres still get served the PWA and not the Wordpress page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the link to manifest file from the html pages similar to listed below, and also remove the manifest file from the domain.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```